# Algorithm to shift a point relative to the position of two other points,

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry

So I have two sets of paths, which I am using to draw lines.

The second line is movable by the users(black line).   They can pick an end and move it in a circle around the other end as a fulcrum.  What I want to do is make the second line move relative to its position to the beginning and end points of the black line.
[image: example of triangles]

I thought I could use the angles of a triangle that each path point makes with the beginning and ending points of the movable black line,  but I can't seem to get it working.  Right now if I move one end even a little it takes the line and add all these loops.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
fun transmuteOutlineWithRatio(angle: Double, newPoint: PointF){
  val tempTries = mutableListOf<Triangle>()

  outlineTriangles.forEach { triangle ->
    //add the angle by which the black line has been moved to the angle of the pathpoint to the fixed point on the movable path.
    val newAngle = angle + (triangle.aAngle?: 0.0)

    val r = getLength(triangle.C, triangle.A)
    val cosX = Math.cos(newAngle)
    val sinY = Math.sin(newAngle)

    val newX = r * cosX
    val newY = r * sinY
    val newTri = triangle.copy(B = newPoint, C = PointF(triangle.C.x+ newX.toFloat(),  triangle.C.y + newY.toFloat()))
    tempTries.add(newTri)
  }
  outlineTriangles.clear()
  outlineTriangles.addAll(tempTries)

}

fun getLength(pointA: PointF, pointB: PointF): Double {
  val xsum = (pointA.x - pointB.x)
  val ysum = (pointA.y - pointB.y)
  val sumOfSquares = (xsum * xsum) + (ysum * ysum)
  return Math.sqrt(sumOfSquares.toDouble())
}
```

and the triangle code:

package com.example.testcanvas

import android.graphics.PointF

```
data class Triangle(var A: PointF,
  var B: PointF,
  var C: PointF,
  var aAngle: Double? = null,
  var bAngle: Double? = null,
  var cAngle: Double? = null) {

  init {
    setAngle(A, B, C)
  }
  

  fun setAngle(pointA: PointF, pointB: PointF, pointC: PointF) {

    val sideA = lengthSquar(pointB, pointC)
    val sideB = lengthSquar(pointA, pointC)
    val sideC = lengthSquar(pointA, pointB)

    val a = Math.sqrt(sideA.toDouble())
    val b = Math.sqrt(sideB.toDouble())
    val c = Math.sqrt(sideC.toDouble())

    var alpha = Math.acos((sideB + sideC - sideA) / (2 * b * c))
    var betta = Math.acos((sideA + sideC - sideB) / (2 * a * c))
    var gamma = Math.acos((sideA + sideB - sideC) / (2 * a * b))

    //convert to degrees
    aAngle = alpha * 180 / Math.PI
    bAngle = betta * 180 / Math.PI
    cAngle = gamma * 180 / Math.PI
  }

  fun lengthSquar(pointA: PointF, pointB: PointF): Float {
    val xDiff = (pointA.x - pointB.x)
    val yDiff = (pointA.y - pointB.y)
    return (xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)
  }

}
```

Comment: I would compute the [distance from each point on the red path to the black line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) (which is the height of those triangles). After rotating the black line, use slope and distance to find the points on the red path.

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve but if it is that if you move/rotate/stretch black line the red one will do the same then I would compute the relative difference transform of black line before and after each change and then apply it on the red line ... so rotation obtained from `atan2(after) - atan2(before)` , scale from `size(after)/size(before)` and ...